# ¿Cómo enviar un mail con Background-image en PHP?

Tags: php, css, email

Estoy haciendo un mail en PHP y no tengo ningún problema en enviarlo ni nada de eso, solo que en el CSS del `body` tengo:

```
body { 
  background-image: url('http://ejemplo.com.mx/background-mail.jpg'); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%;
}
```

En Apple Mail si llega correctamente pero en Gmail, Outlook, y en otros no sale el background solo la típica imagen rota:

[image: Imagen rota]

Alguna ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El tema de la imagen de fondo en los emails no es un tema que le compete a PHP es más bien competencia de HTML y CSS. En este [Link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/) puedes observar las compatibilidades de la etiqueta `background-image` (Debes buscarla de estre todas las etiquetas que se muestran). Por otro lado encontré el siguiente [post](http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth) donde la autora hace una investigación del tema testeando diferentes opciones haciendo el siguiente **VML Hack** donde los resultados son mejores pero con algunos problemas.

```
<td bgcolor="#xxxxxx" background="example.jpg">

<!--[if gte mso 9]>

<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:300px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:1;' src="example.jpg"/>

<v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:300px; width:600px; top:-5; left:-10; border:0; z-index:2;'>

<![endif]-->

<p>Text over background image.</p>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>

</v:shape>

<![endif]-->

</td>
```

Por último aquí algunos otros enlaces para leer e investigar:

- [How to Code HTML Email Newsletters](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/)
- [Comparison of email clients: General features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#General_features)
- [CSS and Email, Kissing in a Tree](http://alistapart.com/article/cssemail)

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Es conocido que `Gmail` tiene problemas con `CSS` y me parece que no es soportada la propiedad `background-image`, en cuanto al cliente `Outlook` el soporte de CSS varía con respecto a la versión.

Como otra opción inserta la imagen como background en una tabla HTML:

```
<table background="http://ejemplo.com.mx/background-mail.jpg">
```